# Oracle apex problem with sigh in how to solve?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I installed **oracle apex** latest version and when i try to log in by using localhost:8080 it prompts me in a sigh in popup page(instead of the actual apex sigh in page) where username and password aren't working , i didn't get any errors or problems during installation , anyone had any similar problem?

https://imageshack.com/i/plnxoozap

Comment: Could you post a screenshot which shows what you got? I can't imagine it.

Comment: https://imageshack.com/i/plnxoozap

Answer (score 0):

What application within Apex are you trying to start? The development environment is available at URL:

```
URL:port/f?p=4500
```

This will ask for a workspace (internal) and the admin user and password you  provided during installation (by running the apxchpwd.sql script).

Comment: the problem is that it never gets me to the apex workspace it prompts me to this username and password, when I type the username and password I provided during installation it acts as if it is invalid. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: What page are you trying to access? Show us the URL.

Comment: sounds like you're trying to login into EM Express instead of APEX

Comment: try localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4500

Comment: same with localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4500